# Recover .ino file from tmp files?

Tags: arduino-ide

Is it possible to recover an .ino file/sketch in/for Arduino? I really need my file back, but ones i uploaded it to my device it vanished from the sketch folder, nor can I find it in the build folder; however, a ton of TMP files are left. Is it possible to use those to recover my .ino file?
They're named something like filename.ino1238437381212.TMP

Comment: Have you looked in them to see what they contain?

Comment: It would seem that all the 20 files contains the old code I was looking for... Do you know why I get so many tmp files with the same code in?

Comment: I would strongly encourage using some form of source control.

Answer (score 6):

Well, stupidly enough, the missing code was inside of the TMP files... in all of them...

Comment: I gather that you solved your problem.  I'm guessing someone reading this with the same probably would want to know more though.  You must have learned something useful between the question and answer, what was that?